# The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ProviderListenable<dynamic> Flutter error

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to get information from other class using riverpod providers. I believe I need HookConsumerWidget in order to get the data and react on it's change. But I'm stuck with this issue of conversion. I do understand they are not the same type and therefore they can't be assigned on each other but what I don't know is how to convert type of List to ProviderListenable. If there is anything I can add on my first question on stackoverflow(go easy on me) I will be more than happy to. Thanks everyone in advance. What I would like to achieve is when user taps on the notification, to mark it as a read which means add it to seenNotifications List. But the functionality is in other class, therefore I decided to use provider in order to get the data. If that is not correct, I'm open to new opinions. I tried getting the data without providers but ofcourse it does not refresh or rebuild the tree so my class is not aware of the user taps. The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type ProviderListenable.

```
` class NotificationBadge extends HookConsumerWidget {
   final Widget? badge;
   final Widget? child;
   final double? top;
   final double? right;
   final Color color;
   final double? left;`
`

   NotificationBadge(
       {Key? key,
       this.badge,
       this.child,
       this.color = AppColor.semantic1,
       this.left,
       this.top,
       this.right});

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
     NotificationCard notificationCard = NotificationCard();
     NotificationsPage notificationsPage = NotificationsPage();

    final notificationsPageProvider = ref.watch(notificationsPage.notifications);
    final notificationsCardProvider = ref.watch(notificationCard.seenNotifications);`

 Code above throws following error - The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the    parameter type 'ProviderListenable<dynamic>

`class NotificationCard extends HookConsumerWidget {
  String? notificationTitle;
  String? notificationSubtitle;
  String? notificationTimeStamp;
  SvgPicture? appLogo;
  late final void onNotificationPressed;
  Function(BuildContext)? deleteFunction;

  NotificationCard({
      this.notificationTitle,
      this.notificationSubtitle,
      this.notificationTimeStamp,
      this.appLogo,
      this.onNotificationPressed,
      this.deleteFunction});

  List seenNotifications = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {

    NotificationsPage notificationsPage = NotificationsPage();
    //NotificationCard notificationCard = NotificationCard();

    final isNotificationRead = useState(false);

    void handleTap() {
      isNotificationRead.value = true;
      seenNotifications.add(notificationsPage.notifications);
      print(notificationsPage.notifications);
      print(seenNotifications);
      // notifyListeners();
    }

    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
          // child: Slidable(
          // Za fazu 2 ubaciti ovaj feature
          // endActionPane: ActionPane(
          //   motion: StretchMotion(),
          //   children: [
          //     SlidableAction(
          //       onPressed: deleteFunction,
          //       icon: Icons.delete,
          //       backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade300,
          //       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          //     )
          //   ],
          // ),
          child: RawMaterialButton(
            elevation: 0,
            // ternary operator here is used for denying multiple clicks
            onPressed: isNotificationRead.value ? null : handleTap,
            fillColor: isNotificationRead.value
                ? AppColor.neutralLight1
                : AppColor.neutralLight3,
            child: ListTile(
              isThreeLine: true,
              title: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 12, bottom: 2),
                child: Text(
                    'Nažalost, tvoj zahtjev za povrat novaca za artikl “Sportska jakna” je odbijen.'),
              ),
              subtitle: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, bottom: 8),
                    child: Text('Razlog?'),
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 32, bottom: 16),
                    child: Text(
                      '06.02.2023. u 10:59',
                      style: AppTypography.smallTextNotification,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              leading: Transform.translate(
                offset: const Offset(5, 10),
                child: Container(
                  child: Assets.images.iconLogoDressap.svg(
                    height: 55,
                    width: 55,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              trailing: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, right: 16),
                child: isNotificationRead.value
                    ? Assets.images.iconNotificationRead.svg(
                        width: 10,
                        height: 10,
                      )
                    : Assets.images.iconNotificiationUnread.svg(
                        width: 10,
                        height: 10,
                      ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
          child: Divider(
            height: 1,
            color: AppColor.neutralDark5,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
`

I tried getting the value without providers which resulted in static behaviour, not responding to user interaction ofcourse.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountering is because you're trying to assign a `List<dynamic>` to a `ProviderListenable<dynamic>` parameter.

To fix this error, you need to ensure that `notificationsPage.notifications` is a `ProviderListenable<dynamic>`.

Also because of your error message looks like you are trying to send the listened state (a list of dynamic items) through a List but listening the wrong property.

Make sure that you are creating your state widget like this one;

```
class NotificationsPage extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<dynamic> _notifications = [];

  List<dynamic> get notifications => _notifications;

  void setNotifications(List<dynamic> notifications) {
    _notifications = notifications;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Then, when you want to update notificationsPage.notifications, use the `setNotifications`

```
notificationsPage.setNotifications([...]);
```

This way, notificationsPage.notifications will be a ProviderListenable, and you can use it with ref.watch() without any type mismatch error.

Comment: I would like to thank you for the quick response and add a comment on this, if I change the previous code from HookWidget to ChangeNotifier as you stated, I get these error messages in other places of the code when trying to call this class - The element type 'NotificationsPage' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are getting this error, this means you are trying to call that class as a widget at your build side. You should wrap your widget with a state notify listener widget I would use 'Consumer' for it. With consumer listen NotificationsPage widget which we extend with ChangeNotifier. Then you can listen those datas in your Consumer's - children widgets.